eulerr Venn/Euler formatting when multiple overlaps observed
Is it at all possible to change the formatting (highlight, font or border line thickness) of a Venn or Euler plot based on the number of overlaps? I had a task to create a Venn diagram of various overlapping factors. It is what they need, but there was a question of whether certain numbers of overlaps could be formatted differently somehow to draw the eye to them.
If we use the eulerr fruits plot, for example (as I imagine Venn and Euler would have the same formatting options):
library(eulerr)

plot(euler(fruits[, 1:4], by = list(sex)), legend = TRUE, quantities = TRUE)

Is it possible to apply any kind of formatting (ideally line thickness but I am open to exploring other options such as label formatting) to the resulting charts where we see banana&apple&orange only?
